# Ways to make callback timer more processing efficient

Tags: c++, timer, callback

Here's a simple callback timer that triggers a corresponding callback as soon as its timer is triggered.
Trick though is constantly "polling" for the next interval can be a waste and I see the program often terminates with a message "processing time exceeded" without even finishing the `Run()`.

On an embedded system, you'd want to use interrupts for timer but would be a preferred approach here? Add to the delay the difference of the next expiry with the current time?
So if current elapsed = 5s, and the next expiry is at 9s, at 4s of delay, but even then it doesn't use the blocking mechanism.

Eventually, I might want to run `Run()` in a thread context.

```
using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
TimePoint start = Clock::now(); 

struct Info
{
    TimePoint t1;
    std::function<void()> f;
};

struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(const Info& info1, const Info& info2) const
    {
        return info1.t1 > info2.t1;
    }
};

std::array<Info, 2> infoList =
{
    Info{TimePoint(std::chrono::milliseconds(9000)), [] { cout << "Ha\n"; }},
    Info{TimePoint(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000)), [] { cout << "Ha1\n"; }}
};

std::priority_queue<Info, std::vector<Info>, Compare> q;

void Run()
{
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        
    //    std::chrono::seconds delay(2);
    //    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);

        TimePoint cur = Clock::now(); 
        auto elapsedMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(cur - start).count();  

        Info info = q.top();
        auto infoMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(info.t1.time_since_epoch()).count();

        if (infoMs >= elapsedMs) // trigger callback as soon as current time elapsed >= t1
        {
          info.f();  
          q.pop();
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    for (const auto& item : infoList)
    {
        q.push(item);
    }

    Run();
}
```

Comment: Calculate the duration to the next item to be executed and use std::condition_variable wait to wait. This is a non-busy wait

Comment: Hm, but who's going to be notifying to unblock the cv? I currently have all in a single `Run()`

Comment: The timeout will unlock the cv, in the cv predicate wait for (anything scheduled, or state of the timer changing to stopping) Assuming you put the whole timer in a class, then the destructor of the timer should set state to stopping and wait for the timer thread to finish

Comment: I couldn't follow your points completely. If you can help with this snippet, that'd be great: https://godbolt.org/z/7MdWeEs76